# Bottomsheet always hiding my last elements of Recyclerview

Tags: android, user-interface, android-recyclerview, android-coordinatorlayout, bottom-sheet

My recyclerview's items are loaded dynamically. The bottom sheet UI is a small music player. I want to show the recyclerview above the music player UI. But currently, the music player UI is hiding the last elements of recyclerview. The music player's ui is hidden/shown dynamically. Can you please show me how the recyclerview's elements can all be shown without being obstructed by the bottomsheet UI(music player)?
Here is my layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/detail_backdrop_height"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/backdrop"
                android:layout_width="200dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                android:transitionName="@string/transition_album_cover"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/my_recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/bottom_ui_container"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/bottom_sheet_behavior">

        <include layout="@layout/music_player_ui" />
    </FrameLayout>


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: did you tried to swap FrameLayot and RecyclerView

Comment: I think that will put the music player behind the recyclerview. This will obstruct music player ui

Comment: Yes, but I thought you want it that way

Comment: I updated the question for a little more clarity

Comment: Temporarily solved the problem by using bottom margin for the recyclerview

Comment: @BaluRaman I did the same thing for now, if you end up finding a better solution please share

Answer (score 1):

Just set paddingBottom and clipToPadding="false" to the recyclerView

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/my_recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:paddingBottom="your_music_player_ui_height" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the height of the `RecyclerView` to "0dip" and if using a `ConstraintLayout`, constrain the `RecyclerView` to the top and bottom of the parent view.

Answer (score 0):

You can fix this issue by putting the recycler view inside the frame layout.

```
<FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/list"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:scrollbars="vertical" />

        </FrameLayout>
```